# Why does asyncio.sleep alllow for the task to not be immediately cancelled?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio

async def cancel_me():
    print('cancel_me(): before sleep')

    try:
        # Wait for 1 hour
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print('cancel_me(): cancel sleep')
        raise
    finally:
        print('cancel_me(): after sleep')

async def main():
    # Create a "cancel_me" Task
    task = asyncio.create_task(cancel_me())

    # if comment out this line we go directly to -> main(): cancel_me is cancelled now
    await asyncio.sleep(1) 
    # This arranges for a CancelledError exception to be thrown into the wrapped 
    # coroutine on the next cycle of the event loop.
    task.cancel()
    try:
        await task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("main(): cancel_me is cancelled now")

asyncio.run(main())
```

With *await asyncio.sleep(1)*, we have:

```
#     Output
#     ------------------------
#     cancel_me(): before sleep
#     cancel_me(): cancel sleep
#     cancel_me(): after sleep
#     main(): cancel_me is cancelled now
```

Without *await asyncio.sleep(1)*, we have:

```
#     Output
#     ------------------------
#     main(): cancel_me is cancelled now
```

- Why is there this difference in output just from commenting out a asyncio.sleep command?

Edit (as a reaction to a comment below):
So, `await asyncio.sleep` allows other tasks to start? This seems counter-intuitive. Does it mean that any `await` after a `create_task` allows any created/scheduled tasks to be started?
Also, consider the following picture:

[image]

I got this picture by commenting out everything that goes below `await asyncio.sleep(1)`, in the main(), and putting `await asyncio.sleep(5)`, instead. In this picture, we see that `cancel_me(): cancel sleep` gets printed, even when we have no task cancel... Not only that, but we do the print in the exception, and don't raise any exception.

Answer (score 2):

With the `await asyncio.sleep(1)` commented out, you cancel the task before it even starts running, so it just doesn't run.

Comment: Isn't the task started when I do `await task`? I thought create_task was for `Wrap the coro coroutine into a Task and schedule its execution.`(taken from official documentation) and not to begin execution...  What you say makes sense given what I get, but the official documentation seems odd.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. `asyncio.create_task` creates a  coroutine. With `await` at  `await asyncio.sleep(1)` the async `main` yields and allows the `cancel_me` to _"start"_ execution. The `await` of `await task` also results `main` to yield, and wait for the `task` to finish, but it does not start the task.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.  coroutines in python (same is true also for various other langauges)  are not done with multiple threads, but in one thread (like cooperative multitasking). An `await` in an `async` function _"pauses"_ the `async` function in which it is used, and allows another `async` function that is queued for execution to run/continue. So `async` functions don't run in parallel but interleaved.

Comment: @t.niese many thanks for your valuable comments. I've edited the question, with some more information. If you could answer those requests, and write an answer, I would accept it. ;)